# Images will not load from Runnable Jar when exported with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jar, runnable

I have spent days searching for a solution to this to no avail... I have tried every suggestion I have seen and still no luck...

My images will not load when running a JAR file exported from Eclipse.

I have the images in a resources class package... I've tried a images source folder as well with no luck.

Works perfectly when loaded from Eclipse...

Here is the code used...

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(MainFrame.class.getResource("/resources/header.jpg")));
```

The images are in the extorted JAR file... so they exporting fine.

I've also tried this...

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/header.jpg");
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Still nothing... :-(

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.denite.lfpc.ui.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:219)
 at com.denite.lfpc.Lfpc$1.run(Lfpc.java:37)

Comment: Where are the resources stored in relationship  to your `src`?  If they are in the `src` directory, they may not be included within the build

Comment: @MadProgrammer I made a resource package... and dragged the images into it... I've tried adding a source folder... that didn't work either... I've read it may just be Eclipse but I can't comprehend not being about to get this working within Eclipse...

Comment: Ultimately, all I want to do with this program is create a standalone EXE file that doesn't rely on an external fold to get images from...

Comment: AFAIK the resource directory should reside at the same level as your `src` directory.  The directory may need to be included within your build process/paths, but I don't use Eclipse so I can't tell you how.  You may consider using `/header.jpg` or `header.jpg` as well if `resources/...` doesn't work

Comment: I did it this way 'cus I found some "solution" somewhere that said to do it that way...

Comment: What is the best program to use to program Java?

Comment: why not use getResourceAsStream(), get Image byte[] data, build ImageIcon from byte[].